# Appropriate routing of the actions Cancel and Store

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes, actionlink

I have a page that lists all the bikes (Bike.cshtml). When an individual bike is clicked, I route to the edit page (BikeEdit.cshtml). At the bottom of the editor, I have two links.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Bikes", "Home")
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Bikes", "Home")
```

Both cases are supposed to lead back to the page listing bikes. Obviously, in the second one I wish to store the alterations of the model object to the DB. I'm tempted to resolve it by sending in the model like so.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Bikes", "Home")
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Bikes", "Home", @Model, null)
```

However, I'm sensing that there's a better way to handle it. There's something unsettling in managing the saving from the controller of the viewer of the bikes.

Another approach I can think of is to add a new action, *BikeSave*, and perform saving in it. However, the view instance returned then won't be based on Bikes.cshtml but BikeSave.cshtml. I can imagine I could use *RedirectToAction* but I feel uncertain. I don't want to design something using "duct tape".

So I'm wobbling my head not being able to decide...

Comment: Why don't you use the Post method for the Edit (assuming you have the Get method)?

Comment: Could you explain a little more, please? Do you mean that I should handle both saving and displaying in Bikes.cshtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user clicks on the update button, you should do a form submit to your HttpPost action method where you will update your db and then redirect to the Home/Bikes page.

Assuming your GET action is like this

```
public ActionResult BikeEdit(int id)
{
  var bikeEditVm=new BikeEditVm { Id=id};
  var bikeEntity = db.Bikes.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id==id);
  if(bikeEntity!=null)
  {
    bikeEditVm.ModelName=bikeEntity.ModelName;
    bikeEditVm.Color=bikeEntity.Color;   
    return View(bikeEditVm); 
  }
  return View("NotFound"); // return a bike not found view to user
}
```

Where `BikeEditVm` is a view model for the edit view, which looks like this

```
public class BikeEditVm
{
  public int Id {set;get;}
  public string ModelName {set;get;}
  public string Color {set;get;}
}
```

In your view which is strongly typed to BikeEditVm, you will keep all your editable fields inside a `form` tag

```
@model BikeEditVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <label>ModelName</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.ModelName)
  <label>Color</label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Color)
  @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.Id)
  <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel","Bikes","Home")
```

You will have an HttpAction method to handle the form posting where you will read the existing entity from database, update the relevant fields you want to update and save it back.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BikeEdit(BikeEditVm model)
{
  var bikeEntity = db.Bikes.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id==model.id);
  if(bikeEntity!=null)
  {
    bikeEntity .ModelName = model.ModelName;
    bikeEntity .Color = model.Color;   
    db.Entry(bikeEntity).State=EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Bikes","Home");
  }
  return View("NotFound");
}
```

**EDIT :** *Answering some questions OP asked in comments here for future readers.*

> (1) I tested to skip [HttpPost] and it works still. Should it?

Anything updating your data should be an HttpPost method.otherwise, people can access your action method via url(GET method) and pass the form field name-values and can try to update your data.(*Your authorization checks may prevent this if exists though*)

> (2) How does your Html.BeginForm() know where to route? I'm using
>   Html.BeginForm(action, controller).

If you do not pass any arguments to `BeginForm` method,It will set the form action value as the current url. Ex : If you are at customer/create GET action view, your form will be posted to customer/create. You can override this behavior by using a different overload where you can specifying a different action method/controller name.

> (3) If I want a field to be passed up/down but not be
>   editable/visible, should I use CSS to hide it? It'd be good to have a
>   control for off-screen storage.

If you do not wish the field to be editable/visible, don't event pass it to your view. Have only those properties in your view model which you really need in your view. Read the next response about how to prevent over posting.

> (4) Is it generally the best idea to have a specialized model for the
>   view instead of using the one from EF?

It is. If you are using the entity classes created by your ORM to transfer data between your action method and view, you are making a tightly coupled solution. What if you decides to not use EF as your data access layer tomorrow for any reason ? Do you want to go and update all your views ? Your view models are specific to a view . So keep only those properties/fields needed for the view. This will also help you to [prevent overposting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260334/mvc-6-bind-attribute-disappears/34260397#34260397).