# Binding new attributes on Controller Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a question regarding Binding of attributes in a Controller's Action.

My model has 3 attributes: Name, UserName and Email:

```
public class User {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

If I want my Create Action to have a new attribute, such as a "Login" Boolean, is there a way to Bind a new attribute to my model, like:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name, UserName, Email, Login")] User model)
```

Or do I must create a ViewModel to do so?

Comment: Create a ViewModel, that's what they are for!

Comment: By default all properties are bound, so its only necessary to use `[Bind(Include="..")]` (or `Exclude`) if your want to prevent some properties from binding. But the correct approach is to use a view model

Answer (score 0):

You can create a viewmodel with all those 4 properties as use that. That is the [best way to prevent overposting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260334/mvc-6-bind-attribute-disappears).

But if you do not want to create a view model. you can definitely add new parameters to your action method. The name of the parameter should match to your corresponding form element name.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name, UserName, Email")] User model,bool Login)
{
   //to do : return something
}
```