# How to pass value Hidden field from database using Entity framework MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using MVC Entity framework i have generated code i have fields Isactive this fields have values true or  false .  code looks like

controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ClientId,ClientName,PrimaryContactName,EmailId,PrimaryContact,IsActive,ModifiedBy,ParentCompany")] TP_InternalClients tP_InternalClients)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tP_InternalClients).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(tP_InternalClients);
        }
```

model:

```
 public class InternalClients
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryContactName { get; set; }
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryContact { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public int ParentCompany { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
 <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

after run the code Isactive drop down showing true or false  i want hidden field that time send value default true only to database . how i can hidden and send value default ? i doing i am getting error

Answer (score 1):

In your form , simply replace

```
<div class="checkbox">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" name="IsActive" value="true" />
```

Or you can use the Html helper method

```
@Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.IsActive)
```

Now make sure you set the default value to whatever you want in the GET action.

**But, If you want a default value to be saved, Do it in your HttpPost action**, No need to keep the Hidden field in the form (Users can update the hidden field value using browser dev tools)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ClientId,ClientName,PrimaryContactName,EmailId,
                       PrimaryContact,ModifiedBy,ParentCompany")] TP_InternalClients model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.IsAcive = true ; 
            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(tP_InternalClients);
}
```

Remember, [the best way to prevent overposting is to use a view model with only those properties needed for the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260334/mvc-6-bind-attribute-disappears).

Comment: value always true  how  can set value default