# MVC set specific properties code side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller

I have a Property `Last_edited` in my Model an want to set this on code side. I also have properties like `Name` which should set by User. I use Code First and this Edit method was generated by Entity Framework. I haven't found anything how to do it.

Here's my Controller Edit method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Product product = db.Product.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(product);
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Comment,Last_edited")] Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
        return View(product);
}
```

Comment: or just leave it like that and set Last_edited also serverside. as an ovverride

Comment: If you only need Last_edited in the code side, and you dont want to display it in your view, just remove ir from your "include" statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Last_edited` from the Include list of `Bind` attribute and set the value yourself in the action method.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Comment")] Product product)
{
    product.Last_Edited = DateTime.UtcNow;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {           
        db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(product);
}
```

Assuming `Last_edited` is of `DateTime` type. if it is a different type, set the appropriate value.

Since we are setting the value of this property in the action method, there is no need to keep an input field for this property in the form.

As a side note, [The best way to prevent overposting is by using a (view specific) view model class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260334/mvc-6-bind-attribute-disappears/34260397#34260397). This also allows you to create loosely coupled programs.

Comment: is'nt better would be to use viewmodel with only propeties that are needed to be passed via view?

Comment: Yes. The best & loosely coupled way to [prevent overposting is by using a view model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260334/mvc-6-bind-attribute-disappears/34260397#34260397). The OP is new to MVC and is playing with the code generated by the IDE. I did not want to confuse him. I will update the answer to include the link

Comment: yeah, that would be good to add, that better approach is this for future readers..